# Trouble converting dates read in from excel

Tags: r, lubridate, as.date

I have a data set that the date/time is formatted like this in excel

3/11/2020  8:12:00 PM

3/12/2020  7:13:00 PM

When I read the file in, the date/time is converted to this.  I would like to convert this to
Month/day/year.

43901.84

43902.80

I have tried a number of solutions here but have not been able to correct this.

Comment: For the first, `as.Date(43901.84, origin = "1899-12-30")` returns `[1] "2020-03-11"`. See `help("as.Date")`, there's an example with Excel dates.